# "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type” in a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I have defined the following structure in my header `path.h`:

```
typedef struct path Path;

struct Path {

   Path* branching_paths; 
   uint32_t nb_paths;
};
```

and in the same header I have declared and defined the following inline function:

```
  inline void init_path(Path* path);

  inline void init_path(Path* path){

     path->branching_paths = NULL;
     path->nb_paths = 0;
 }
```

And I don't know for what reason I am getting this error.. I already searched the web but as far as I see i have defined the structure properly in the header, or am I missing something?

```
./../Path.h:54:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'Path {aka struct path}'
     path->branching_paths = NULL;
```

Comment: That is because struct path is not the same as struct Path.

Comment: but if i type typedef struct path Path, haven't I called it then Path??

Comment: what is `struct path`?

Comment: ok I got it i Think, I guess it should be: `struct path {....} `.
But does than also my first variable "branching path" needs to be with `struct path* branching path`??

Comment: Because of the `typedef` line, you can use `Path *branching_path`, or if you go with `struct path`, you can use `struct path *branching_path`, or if you use `struct Path`, you can use `struct Path *branching_path`.  As long as the `struct tag` matches, you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `typedef`.

You define a `typedef` for `struct path`, then you later define `struct Path`.  Because C is case sensitive, these are seen as two separate types.

The way you have it now, you declared `struct path` (with `Path` as an alias) but haven't defined it.  So when you try to dereference a `Path *`, the compiler doesn't know what that struct looks like because you haven't told it.

What you want is:

```
typedef struct Path Path;
```

Comment: It was not a typo, I think I just didn't understand by now that by writing:  `typedef struct path Path` I define the struct path as Path, so of course "struct path" hasn't been defined then. Right?

Comment: @malajedala: yes, at the end of the typedef, `struct path` is not defined.  The trouble is that at the end of `struct Path { … };`, `struct path` has still not been defined.  You need `typedef struct Path Path;` as the simplest fix.

Comment: yes that is true, thanks! I will do it that way, its the simplest. However it was good making this mistake so now I really understand whats happening behind those commands! Thanks